# tableview Navigation error

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uinavigationbar

In my tableview xib i couldn't be able to show navigation bar on run time? My coding as follows

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
ar=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"When im happy..i...",@"When im sad.. i...",@"When i'm mad.i...",@"My worst habbit is....",@"The best thing about me is...",nil];
[super viewDidLoad];
self.title=@"Welcome";

self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem=self.editButtonItem;
}
```

The table view doesnt showing the navigation bar.Please help me out

Comment: do u have navigation base app...

Comment: @Rajneesh071 No.i just open this tableview from uiview button click.

Comment: MAke your controller a navigationController or add a navigationbar onto the view manually only then you can see the navigation bar

Comment: do you have navigation bar in your tableView....if not then how can you think to set navigation bar button...

Comment: that is what my problem.its not showing the navigation bar?@Rajneesh071

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you creating **self.editButtonItem**? 
Use this code:-

```
 [self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:[[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Test" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(test:)]autorelaese]];
```

Comment: paste some code.You are unable to show Navigation.You have View Controller?

Comment: - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
    ar=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"When im happy..i...",@"When im sad.. i...",nil];
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.title=@"Welcome";
    
    [self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"next" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(next)]];
    
}
    -(void)next
     {
    signature *nextview=[[signature alloc]initWithNibName:@"signature" bundle:nil];
    [self presentModalViewController:nextview animated:YES];
    }

Comment: i am modifying your code-use in -(void)ViewDidLoad{[self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"next" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(next)]];} and target must be out side of the ViewDidLoad.like -(void)next:(id)sender{paste code for opening a new view controller}.I corrected it.it working fine.

Comment: you have your Navigation ref?, if not you should create first.